# Is there a way to pinch and zoom a programmatically added image?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am trying to figure out how to add pinch/zoom capabilities to an imageView, 
but specifically to one that I added to the scrollView programmatically.  I was able to find some great examples on SO to pinch and zoom an image using a scrollview with viewForZooming, but in that instance I had to return the image view being pinched and zoomed, which doesn't work if I am returning it programatically.

My ultimate goal is to have an array of images where the user can scroll left and right to see all the images AND be able to zoom in on them, basically just as if they were flipping through their photoStream.  I found an ok tutorial for adding the images dynamically for scrolling here https://www.codementor.io/taiwoadedotun/ios-swift-implementing-photos-app-image-scrolling-with-scroll-views-bkbcmrgz5#comments-bkbcmrgz5 but I am not clear how to add the viewForZooming since the image views are being .addSubview dynamically in a loop.

I created a little example with a collection view of 0-n images associated to a post.  Once the collectionViewCell with the image is tapped a hidden scrollView appears with a new dynamic UIImageView added as a subView.  All works great but I don't know how to add the pinch/zoom now.

```
@objc func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("BlipeFile Image Tapped")
    let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
    //newImageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    newImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    newImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    newImageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
    newImageView.frame = self.view.frame
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .black
    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    newImageView.image = imageView.image
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    scroller.isHidden = false
    scroller.addSubview(newImageView)
}

@objc func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    scroller.isHidden = true
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}


func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return image //Can't return dynamically created newImageView?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My ultimate goal is to have an array of images where the user can scroll left and right to see all the images AND be able to zoom in on them

Apple has explained many times, in WWDC videos and in sample code that you can download, how this is done. Basically it’s just a scroll view in a scroll view. The outer scroll view permits scrolling horizontally. The inner scroll view contains an image view and permits zooming.

So instead of adding an image view, add a scroll view containing an image view.

Comment: googled around a little adding WWDC to the search, is this something like you are suggesting?  I think it is from 2010 so not sure its still best.  If you have a good link for me to get  tutorial on this that would be very helpful!  https://medium.com/@ssamadgh/designing-apps-with-scroll-views-part-ii-page-scrolling-on-photos-948f78d2f683